# Execute service function after array populated

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service in angular 4 application with the following constructor:

```
constructor(private readonly http: Http) {
    this.http.get(this.originUrl + 'api/ProductCategories/').subscribe(result => {
        this.categories = result.json();
    });
}
```

and also a function in this service to get one's category Id.

```
findCategory(fullSlug: string): number {
    return this.categories.filter(c=>c.fullSlug == fullSlug)[0].id;
}
```

I need to call this function from a component after the categories list is populated. After the app is loaded once, it's ok cause service is loaded from app.module but when I reload the page (F5) i get the error "Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined" in findCategory function.

Thanks.

Comment: show how do you use this `findCategory` method and tell me please, what is relation betwen this sth with constructor and this with `findCategory` method

Comment: In component i use
constructor(private categoriesService: CategoriesService) {}
to get the instance and on ngAfterViewInit i use 
this.categoryId = this.categoriesService.findCategory(this.catStr);

Answer (score 1):

I since your `this.categories` property is being populated *async*, you need to take that into account when using it in another public method that you don't control from inside the service.

**UPDATE:**
Since it turned out to be important in this case that the data was only retrieved once from the data source, I propose going full observable from the service instead. Meaning the service will always return observable results, and always let the consumers handle the subscription.

The trick to only load the data once is to use the `share` operator. It will make the `categories$` observable *hot* ([read more on the topic here](https://medium.com/@benlesh/hot-vs-cold-observables-f8094ed53339)). Put short - it will only go to the data source once, and then let all subscribers share the already retrieved result (see updated code below).

<strike>I would suggest delegating the responsibility of subscribing to the categories to the consumers of the service, and then add the data you want to do the filtering on as a parameter to the `filter` function.</strike>

This assures you the you always work with loaded data when doing the filtering.

In the service (`YourService.ts` for now):

```
originUrl = "....";
categories$: Observable<YourCategoryType[]>;

constructor(private readonly http: Http) {
  this.categories$ = this.http.get(this.originUrl + 'api/ProductCategories/')
    .map(res => res.json())
    .share(); // <- Makes sure the call is only made ones, then re-uses the result
}

findCategory(fullSlug: string): Observable<number> {
    return this.categories$
      .map(cats => cats.filter(cat => cat.fullSlug === fullSlug)[0].id);
}
```

And in a consumer, for example a component:

```
categoryId: number;

constructor(private yourService: YourService) {}

someMethod(fullSlug: string) {
  this.yourService
    .findCategory(fullSlug)
      .subscribe(catId => this.categoryId = catId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is I used categories: YourCategoryType[]; in service so i can query database only the first time app is loaded. Service categories property is used to populate another component which is a menu with categories. Then in products component i need to query the created categories object to get the id from the fullSlug.

Comment: Thanks Fredrik. I'm not sure it's correct. Maybe I'm missing something. You suggest this.categories$.filter. But categories$ is an Observable<ProductCategory[]>. There is no fullSlug in ProductCategory[] but in ProductCategory. This works:

Comment: return this.categories$.map(c=>c.filter(cat=>cat.fullSlug == fullSlug)[0].id);. I think you meant this.
Also .share() doesn't seem to work. Anytime function is called the api is called and the querying the db. Here is the service file: https://gist.github.com/dseferlis/398b134153aceedcd5948fa93f9c0486

Answer (score 0):

It's really unpredictable and you have no way to control the http-request when having it in the constructor in Service.

I'd suggest you'd have a "helper" method instead, so that you can control the flow. In that helper method we can just check if `categories$` is `undefined`. If it is, make the http-call. Then just use that method in your service and perform your magic ;) So something like this in your service:

```
categories$: Observable<ProductCategory[]>

getCategories() {
  if(this.categories$ === undefined) {
    this.categories$ = this.http.get(this.originUrl + 'api/ProductCategories/')
      .map(res => res.json())
  } 
  return this.categories$
}
```

Then, as mentioned, in your other service methods, just call the above one... so, eg when calling `findCategory` from your component, this would be going on in your service:

```
findCategory(fullSlug: string): number {
  return this.getCategories()
    .map(data => data.filter(c => c.fullSlug == fullSlug)[0].id)
}
```

..to which result you can then subscribe to in component.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's in constructor. Constructor is not called more than once. I think it's the .map that tells app anytime categories$ asked to execute the get. I tried your suggestion with same results. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Yes it's called only once, but then you get this kinds of errors, since you cannot control it, therefore when you refresh your `categories$` is undefined. With above code that error won't happen. The above code should work fine, could you reproduce the issue in a plunker or something?

Comment: The problem, as with Fredrik's answer, is that http.get runs every time even if categories$ is not undefined. Check these: https://i.imgur.com/yViN4du.png https://i.imgur.com/gVHvOlL.png
as you can see the categories$ is undefined only the 1st time a category is asked (id: 357). On the next call (id: 30) is defined so "Categories is undefined" doesn't display but on server i get hit on:
Executing action method Kappakosgr.Web.Controllers.ProductsController.Get (Kappakosgr.Web) with arguments ((null)) - ModelState is Valid.
I will try put this on plunker but is not easy to include the api.

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand how the http-request can be called if `categories$` is defined. I mean even your console log tells us that the `if` statement is not hit, so therefore http-request shouldn't be made at all. I must be missing something here since I don't understand this now :P